# How to add images to iphone simulator v4

Tags: iphone, image, import, simulator

I've always been able to get images into iphone simulator 3 by the usual methods described on this site (i.e. dragging image into iphone simulator).

However, having upgarded to the new xcode 3.2.3, although I can still save images to the simulator, I can't actually see them there when I go to the library on the simulator.

Thankfully - it works when I build for the iPad simulator.

Has anyone else go this problem or is my install of the new xcode screwy?

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed that you can add them if you change the device in the Hardware menu. Switch to iPhone and do the usual. Then switch back to iPhone4 and you'll be able to see the images in the photo library.

[alt text http://img.skitch.com/20100705-8kra9hetayjqhyu3i5w4brayr4.png](http://img.skitch.com/20100705-8kra9hetayjqhyu3i5w4brayr4.png)

You should also file a radar with Apple. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I was had the same problem after v4 upgrade but it seems to work if I drag the images into an album in the actual 'photos' app.

Answer (score 0):

You can save images in the simulator by going to Safari on the iPhone,iPad. 
Navigate to some URL eg, hot pictures of Megan Fox on google images. Click and hold on your favourite image of here, hopefully in a very hot pose. Then select save from the menu that appears.

This normally does it for me.

[UPDATED] 
Sorry this does not work on 3.2.2 but has worked in the past.

Comment: Thank John. That's what I normally do too (but not with Megan Fox). I just tried again, this time using Megan Fox but again, although it looked like it was saving, when I got to select an image from the image library, it is not there in the iphone os 4 simulator. However, it is there when I use the iPad simulator.

Have you managed to get this working on the latest xcode (3.2.3) ?

Comment: Oh... Man this has worked for ages. Does not work on 3.2.2 what a drag. Ok now I need to know how to do this. Maybe write some code to save images to the users library, its only a few lines.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you need to run the Photos app on the simulator after dragging in images in order for it to make the images available from your app.

Answer (score 0):

First you simply run simulator then tap on back button after this drag image from your macbook u found small image on simulator screen hold courser on image 
after a while bring a pop-up screenView on iPhone simulator screen to ask that you want to save this image or cancel
you just save and go back 
open photo gallery you must be see one image in photo gallery